# Select com Update

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Alguém saberia dizer se existe um camando SQL para executar um `SELECT` usando `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` no registro e executando um UPDATE ao mesmo tempo? exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM Nome_Tabela WHERE id = 5 LOCK IN SHARE MODE (UPDATE AQUI)
```

Alguma sugestão? Estou usando MySQL.

Comment: Usar LOCK IN SHARE MODE em uma atualização, não é muito recomendável, pois se dois usuários estiverem lendo o mesmo conteúdo, um deles acabará se perdendo quando o valor for atualizado. Para implementar a leitura de um determinado valor, primeiro realize o bloqueio de leitura do mesmo, utilizando FOR UPDATE e depois incremente o valor. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 1):

Se sua intenção é "*dar um lock*" no registro para que ninguém altere antes que você faça o seu *update*, recomendo usar o **FOR UPDATE**.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT nome FROM clientes WHERE nome = 'josé' FOR UPDATE; UPDATE clientes SET nome = 'josé das couves';
```

Referência [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).